# Automatically solve rm cannot remove path : device or resource busy error

Tags: linux, bash, unix, rm, lsof

I am trying to remove a directory `/path/to/dir` using the `rm -rf` command.
Unfortunately I get the error

```
rm: cannot remove '/path/to/dir/.nfsdda293a660f276ca0000000a': Device or resource busy
```

After a little bit of research, I realized that I need to find which process is using this file before I can delete it:

```
lsof /path/to/dir/.nfsdda293a660f276ca0000000a
```

which will return something with the PID associated with the process:

```
COMMAND   PID
python    28594
```

I then kill the PID and try again to delete, but I still get the initial error.

How to force the script to delete `/path/to/dir` automatically within a script, without manual intervention?

Comment: Do in the script exactly what you do manually.  Capture the output of `lsof` to get the PID to kill and kill it the same method as you would manually.

Comment: @Nic3500, why use lsof then instead of `fuser -k` to do both steps (find the process _and kill it_) at once?

Answer (score 7):

This worked for me:

```
lsof +D /path
```

That will recurse through the filesystem under /path, so beware doing it on large directory trees.

Once you know which processes have files open, you can exit those apps, or kill them with the kill(1) command.

Credit:
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/11238/how-to-get-over-device-or-resource-busy

Answer (score 2):

With so many complicated answers on here which is confusing everybody, please just do the following.

```
umount directoryname
```

then try again
e.g.

```
rm -rf directoryname
```

Comment: `umount` doesn't work while there are open handles, unless using `-f` (to "force" the unmount and make future syscalls made by the running programs fail) or `-l` (a "lazy" unmount, that only does half the job immediately and does the other half when the handles are closed... meaning that the filesystem isn't _really_ released immediately).

Answer (score 1):

In case the [@Hayden](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71993240/15545196) answer didn't help you (returns nothing or such), this command can be handy:

```bash
umount /path
```

---

[credit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/122851)